# Javascript does not show data obtained from PHP and SQL Server

Tags: javascript, php, json, sql-server

I'm new to PHP and I have little knowledge of Javascript, I'm trying to create a chronometer that the time limit is obtained from a database (SQL SERVER), so when you get the value in PHP and assign it to a variable of Javascript function, I get a -1.

From what I read it appears to me that the PHP object type is not the same as in Javascript and this can be solved with json_encode (), however it keeps appearing -1.

```
 <?php
  require('db.php');
  if ($connection) 
  { 
    $TimEva = 60;
    $rs = odbc_exec($connection,"SELECT time FROM DBO.tablaCrono cr WHERE cr.id = '$EncIdx';");   
    while(odbc_fetch_row($rs))
    {
      $TimEva=odbc_result($rs,"TimEva");
    }
    echo "<div align='center'><h1><label id = 'tiempo'>".$TimEva."</label></h1></div>";
    $rs = odbc_close($connection);
    }
  else
  {
    echo "<div align='center'>no se pudo conectar</div><br />";
  }
 ?>
```

And in the Javascript function I have the following

```
var label = document.getElementById("tiempo"),
minutos = <?php  echo json_encode($TimEva,JSON_HEX_TAG);?>,
```

I expect 60, which is the value in the database, it shows up well in html, but the value of the variable minutes, throws -1

I could be guided, help, use AJAX, I'm really a bit lost.

Comment: The thing you need to appreciate is that PHP is only active and present when the page is server side, once the page is downloaded to the client, the JavaScript is active and the PHP is no longer running.  Is the page output formatted correctly, do you have html tags and body tags ?  Are the page headers sent before the content?  Headers like content-type, content-length ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  $rs = odbc_exec($connection,"SELECT `time` FROM DBO.tablaCrono cr WHERE cr.id = '$EncIdx';");
```

Change your query to this. `time` is a word used from the language so if you want to use it as a column you need to escape it.

Also modify your JS code to something like :

```
<script>
    var label = document.getElementById("tiempo")
    var minutos = <?php  echo json_encode($TimEva,JSON_HEX_TAG);?>
    console.log(minutes)
</script>
```

Then open your console window and see what is the value that your variable has.

Lastly ensure that you actually have a value in `$EncIdx` variable cause we don't see how you assign a value to it. I guess it's in a part of the code you did not share.

Comment: Ok, it throws me null and then -1

Comment: echo `$EncIdx` in your php script and check what is it's value. Do you have a value there? Based on your code this is an undefined variable.

Comment: yes, on the page other queries are based on this parameter
 if(!empty($_GET['id'])) 
 {
  $EncIdx = $_GET['id']; 
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
            function tiempo()
            {


                var label = document.getElementById("tiempo"),

                minutos   = <?php  echo json_encode($TimEva,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);?>,
                segundos  = 0,
                intervalo = setInterval(function(){
                            console.log(minutos)


                    if (--segundos < 0){
                        segundos = 59;
                        minutos--;
                    }

                    if (!minutos && !segundos)
                    {
                        clearInterval(intervalo);
                        alert("Lo sentimos se termino el tiempo");
                        //document.evaluacion.submit();
                    }

                    label.innerHTML = minutos + ":" + (segundos < 10 ? "0" + segundos : segundos);
                }, 1000);
            }
        </script>
```